# why doesnt jquerymobile swipe work on both my mobile phones, samsung s3 and samsung galaxy?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am having a problem with jquerymobile using the swipe feature, i am trying to swipe left and right to open and close menus although it works with click e.g drag click but when i use to screen it does not.

my page is http://www.2click4.com/new/mobile/untitled.html

```
$( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#page", function( e ) {
            // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
            // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
            // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
            if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
                if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
                    $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                    $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                }
            }
        });
```

this is the main code for swiping although works fine on pc, does not work on mobile! can anyone help? i am new to this.